# how questions are classified as interesting?

Tags: discussion, questions

Just curious to know, how stackoverflow classifies questions as interesting ? What are the parameters which decides that ?

But when I look at the questions marked interesting for me, those questions not completely satisfies my history but belong to one of my favourite tags. There are few questions that are neither from my history nor from my tags.

Comment: On SO, interesting questions are those with less than 10 dups :)

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Wait.. what?

Answer (score 1):

It is *based on your history and tag preference*.
If you just hover your mouse over the 'interesting' tab, you can see the same.

EDIT:

The exact phrase used is (emphasis mine):

> Questions that **may be** of interest to you based on your history and tag
>   preference

It appears to be some kind of machine learning in play here, so it is expected to improve with time. Also, the use of 'may be' clearly says that history and tag preferences are not the only two parameters (but maybe the two most important ones?)

Comment: Right after hovering it shows the details. But when I look at the questions marked interesting for me, those questions not completely satisfies my history but belong to one of my favourite tags. There are few questions that are neither from my history nor from my tags. So, still I'm not convinced by the history/tag way of classification. What is your view ?